# Special characters in bash prompt not working (colored username)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

I am using:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1) 
green=$(tput setaf 2)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
export PS1="\[$red\]\u\[$reset\]@\[$green\]\h\[$reset\]:\[$blue\]\w\[$reset\]\$ "
export EDITOR=nano
```

This is what shows:
[]\u[]@[]\h[]:[]\w[]$

How can I fix this? Seems like bash does not interprete the special characters.

Comment: Which terminal are you using here?

Comment: Nice use of variables! It works for me. What's the output of `echo $TERM` for you?

Comment: Are you sure you're running bash? Where did you put these lines? They should be in `~/.bashrc` and you shouldn't export `PS1`, which is a shell setting and not an environment variable. If the lines aren't in `.bashrc`, put them there and read [this](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980).

Comment: echo $TERM shows xterm-color. Does the same on another system I have where it works, so I think that should be good.

Removed the export, no success :). Thx for the link, good read.

Comment: Now echo $PS1 shows me :" $ ". I previously logged in as root, then switched to another user. Now, when logging in via that user directly it shows no $PS1. Also, trying to autocomplete does not work, as well as pressing the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The users were using /bin/sh not /bin/bash

Changing this resolved all the issues I had.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that, in your example output, the shell prompt still has the square brackets and escapes suggests that something's a bit screwy with your quoting locally, but what you pasted in your question *does* work for me in a simple cut-n-paste using bash 4.1.5(1)-release.

Comment: Now using:

red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
color=$("\[$red\]\u\[$reset\]@\[$green\]\h\[$reset\]:\[$blue\]\w\[$reset\]\$ ")
PS1="$color"
export EDITOR=nano

Does not help.

It works on all my other systems, how can I check my 4.1.5 release?